# Can't click on button when float right

Tags: css, angular

I have created a form that adds input dynamically  with an add and remove button. I would place them on the right

I can't click on remove button exept the lastet one

[image: here an exemple]

**HTML** file:

```
    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Constituez votre équipe</ng-template>
        <div formArrayName="pers" *ngFor="let control of secondFormGroup.controls.pers.controls; let i= index">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Nom collaborateur #{{i+1}}" [formControl]="control.controls.name" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Poste" [formControl]="control.controls.poste" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button *ngIf="secondFormGroup.controls.pers.controls.length > 1" (click)="deleteItem()" mat-mini-fab color="warn" class="rightButton"><mat-icon >remove</mat-icon>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div>{{secondFormGroup.value | json}}</div>


        <button (click)="addItem()" mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="rightButton"><mat-icon >add</mat-icon>
              </button>
    </form>
</mat-step>
```

**CSS** file :

```
.rightButton {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

When I disable `rightButton` class on the remove button , I could click on all of the buttons without a problem but they are not right positioned as I want.

Comment: you should be having it as `position : absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: try adding z-index:9999;

Comment: use `z-index` property.

Comment: also, try clearing floats for each set. You can use after pseudoelement for it

Comment: When you use float right,you just show it not necessary they are in the proper z-index so you can use the z-index css to correct or use another properties of positioning like display flex justify content end.

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
.rightButton {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    float: right;
}
```

This will make the button to be on top of all the HTML elements on the form. The z-index property only works on positioned elements (absolute, relative, fixed, and sticky)

Comment: Yes it is. It only affects positioned elements (relative and absolute).

Comment: @Tibs Could you please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Hi, @SantiagoM.Quintero sorry for the very late reply. I have edited my post and added an explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me z-index didnt work.

There was something in front of that button that is not visible. Making the button as a separate row helped.

In Bootstrap 4 this is how I made it a separate row:

```
<div class="row block-section">
   <a data-placement="top" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
     href="#" onclick="deleteClicked('video1');return false;">Delete </a>
</div>
```

Then it started working on mobile device even with

> float: right